# Pop up message to users in OU

Tags: powershell

since the netsend command has been removed in vista and windows 7 is there a way to send a popup message to all the users in a Domain or in a specific OU?

The folling code gets the Pop up message, but how can i make this popup on the OU computers or users?

(New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell).popup("this is a one line popup")

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

msg.exe replaced net send for Vista and above OSes to send out messages to other computers.

msg.exe

Send a message to a user.

MSG {username | sessionname | sessionid | @filename | *}
    [/SERVER:servername] [/TIME:seconds] [/V] [/W] [message]

username
Identifies the specified username.

sessionname
The name of the session.

sessionid
 The ID of the session.

@filename

Identifies a file containing a list of usernames,sessionnames, and sessionids to send the message to.

'*

Send message to all sessions on specified server.

/SERVER:servername

server to contact (default is current).

/TIME:seconds
Time delay to wait for receiver to acknowledge msg.

/V
 Display information about actions being performed.

/W
 Wait for response from user, useful with /V.

message
       Message to send.  If none specified, prompts for it
                      or reads from stdin.